# App "flavours" with different icons show up with the same icon in schemes

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I have one app target with several different build configurations (not to be confused with several targets with two configurations each).
I have created one scheme per configuration, meaning I can click the drop-down-menu and select which configuration of the app I should build and run. In this drop-down list, *all the apps have the same icon*.

To be clear, when running the apps on devices(or simulator) they all get their correct icon. In the end, everything is correct when installed.

This is just annoying. It's just this list. and it has always been like this (as long as I can remember). I haven't really bothered with finding out why it is like this until now.

Until today, all the apps in the drop-down used the same icon, but that icon was the "main" icon for this project. The icon of the "main app", which was the first "flavour". After I updated to **Xcode 10** today, they all still have identical icons, but it's a different icon than it used to be. It's the icon for one of the least important build configurations.[image: scheme list]

It should be looking like this:
[image]

(This is from another project where we used several targets with two configurations instead of a single target with several configurations)

Is there a way to fix this? Or control which icon is used?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your issue?

Comment: @Malloc Nope. But it doesn't affect the product. Simply a minor inconvenience when developing.

Comment: _Update: this is still the case for **Xcode 13**._